# Return all values of QuerySet and serialize into JSON

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-models

With this code all of the values are specified to return a QuerySet

```
import json

posts = (Post.objects.filter(owner=authenticated_user)
                 .values('id', 'title', 'summary'))
json_posts = json.dumps(list(posts))
```

Is there a way to avoid specifying all of the values for the QuerySet ('id', 'title', and 'summary')?  For example

```
posts = (Post.objects.filter(owner=authenticated_user)
                 .values(ALL VALUES))
```

**EDIT:**

Ultimately the goal is to serialize the QuerySet into JSON. The following code raises an AttributeError

```
try:
    obj = SystemOverview.objects.filter(serial=pk).values()
except SystemOverview.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
    return Response(serializers.serialize("json", list(obj)))

#ERROR MESSAGE
#AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

What is the correct way of serializing a Django object model into JSON without listing all of its values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values

> The values() method takes optional positional arguments, *fields,
>   which specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited. If
>   you specify the fields, each dictionary will contain only the field
>   keys/values for the fields you specify. **If you don’t specify the
>   fields, each dictionary will contain a key and value for every field
>   in the database table**.

Simply use `Post.objects.filter(owner=authenticated_user).values()`

**EDIT:**

```
objs = SystemOverview.objects.filter(serial=pk).values()

if request.method == 'GET':
    return Response(serializers.serialize("json", objs))
```

Comment: Thanks @rrmerugu. Would you happen to know why the AttributeError appears (edit above) when I use values() instead of values('id')?

Comment: also, if you want to get all values, why do you even need to specify them ? why not use simply `obj = SystemOverview.objects.filter(serial=pk)`. (a silly correction use `objs` instead of `obj`, filter will give list of objects)

Comment: you are making a list(obj) in serialize step, but in actual you already get the list of queryset when you used filter, that must be creating the error, try my edited answer

Comment: did that fixed the issue